# PendingIntent get requestCode

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I use an `AlarmManager` to start a service. When i set up the `AlarmManager` i use the `PendingIntent` and use a unique requestCode which is equal to a id row in my database.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SettingsActivity.this,
                            lecture.getId(), myIntent, 0);
```

How can I retrieve that id in my service when it starts? I basically need only the requestCode parameter. I want to use that id to retrieve data from my database and show it in a notification. I have implemented all the stuff, I just need that requestCode. Is it possible to get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to put `lecture.getId()` into extras of your `myIntent`. According to Javadoc [requestCode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) is not even used yet.

```
// store id
myIntent.putExtra("id", lecture.getId());

// read id or -1, if there is no such extra in intent
int id = myIntent.getIntExtra("id", -1);
```

Comment: But I need that id even when the app is killed. When an app is killed the extra data is deleted. How can i get the necessary data from the database on the service when the id in the extras will be null? Or am I wrong on this?

Comment: @Aksiom the `PendingIntent` when got fired will have the extra, it has nothing to do with process getting killed, `PendingIntent` is sort of intent which run independently from the app, even if your app is not running!!

Comment: @Aksiom but when device is booted(restarted) `PendingIntent` will get removed so **on boot** you have to re-register the `PendingIntent` with the `AlarmManager`

Comment: `AlarmManager` will keep `Intent` for you, even if your app is stopped. Once there is alarm time, `AlarmManager` will launch your app again and send your intent to your broadcast receiver. No information will be lost. `AlarmManager` removes the data when your phone is restarted or you cancel the intent only.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar ok thanks for the info. Can you explain how to re-register the `PendingIntent` on device boot?

Comment: @Aksiom check out the link beworker provided! and for more details on `BroadcastReceivers` refer to http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html